# How do I make my emojis look beautiful in emoji-mart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

I am using **emoji-mart** in react js (typescript) project

**emoji-mart documentation:** https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart

Now the emojis are showing like this:
[image: Image 1]

But, I want to make these like this:
[image: Image 2]

**Note:** I tried to make it by using the "set:apple, facebook etc" according to this https://missiveapp.com/open/emoji-mart document. But, I am getting this:
[image: hash image]

**Can you help me?**

Comment: I'm quite certain it depends on the browser bring used, as different OS's and browsers have different emoji display thingamajigs.

Answer (score 3):

Specify

```
import emojiMartData from '@emoji-mart/data/sets/[version]/apple.json';
```

In Picker, specify:

```
data={emojiMartData}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure it out myself for a good hour or more, and **finally got this thing to work on a TypeScript/React file**.
This is my code, give it a build or good Ctrl/Cmd+F5 (On your browser) on your keyboard to work (Just in case):

```
// App.tsx

import './App.css'

/*

// This version of the dataset does not work if you're trying to use Apple emojis

 import data from '@emoji-mart/data'

 */
// Use this instead for Apple emojis, I am using "appleEmojisData" as a name for the emoji data-set, but you could name it anything like data, myApplesAreYellow or something absolutely crazy :D

import appleEmojisData from '@emoji-mart/data/sets/14/apple.json'
import Picker from '@emoji-mart/react'

function App() {

  return (
    <Picker data={appleEmojisData} set="apple" onEmojiSelect={console.log} />
  )
}

export default App
```

Please note that `set="apple"` is needed along with `data={appleEmojisData}`